# What is this property of a group action called?

Tags: group-actions

Suppose we have a group $G$ acting on a topological space $X$, and there exists a $contractible$ open set $U$ in $X$ such that the orbit of $U$ is $X$.

Comment: I'm not aware of a name for this. Any particular reason you're interested in it?

Comment: Algebraic topology.  Maybe a better question would be what to call such a U or the cover provided by U.  Maybe a "G-equivariant cover of X by contractible open sets"?